# Django: include paths with pk

Tags: django, path, django-views

I'm developping an app that uses context processors, the function within the context processors is executed only if it doesn't belong to any of the paths specified as follows:

```
if request.path != "/details/" and \
            request.path != "/live/":
     # EXECUTE FUNCTIONS
```

However, I'm not managing to include a path that has pk included on it. I've tried the following: `request.path != "/live/<int:pk>` without results. Any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up doing the following :

```
+    if request.path != "/backtest/details/" and \
+            request.path != "/live/details/" and \
+            request.path[-7:] != "delete/" and \
+            request.user.is_authenticated:
```

So just looking at the last characters of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Very basic example but i would do something like this. I would create a list of url paths and the check the request.path against the urls list.I am not sure if you can pass a pk inside a context processor.An other way is to write a custom template tag.

```
from django.urls import reverse

urls = [reverse("home"), reverse("detail",kwargs={"pk":pk})]

if request.path not in ulrs:
   some code
```